# Parse directory locations from file in c++

Tags: c++, regex

Hi I have txt files like this :

```
 Directory of C:\Users\RDep

01/09/2014  05:10 PM    <DIR>          .
01/09/2014  05:10 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/07/2014  09:32 PM               569 GNU CLISP 2.49.lnk
01/07/2014  09:38 PM               493 lsp 23.fas
01/07/2014  09:38 PM                28 lsp 23.lib
01/07/2014  09:35 PM                35 lsp 23.lsp
01/09/2014  05:02 PM    <DIR>          Sigma
01/09/2014  05:10 PM    <DIR>          Sxz
               4 File(s)          1,125 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\RDep\Sigma

01/09/2014  05:02 PM    <DIR>          .
01/09/2014  05:02 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\RDep\Sxz

01/09/2014  05:10 PM    <DIR>          .
01/09/2014  05:10 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/09/2014  05:10 PM                 0 Zop.txt
               1 File(s)              0 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               5 File(s)          1,125 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  46,734,090,240 bytes free
```

I just know the parent directory Is : C:\Users\RDep\ (It  depend on user choice and may change during run time) . And the structure Is sth like above code .

Those other names and formats are unknown ( zop.txt -lsp 23.lsp ,... )

Now I want to locate :

```
C:\Users\RDep
lsp 23.fas
lsp 23.lib
lsp 23.lsp

C:\Users\RDep\Sigma
Zop.txt

C:\Users\RDep\Sxz
```

I cant find any useful pattern for finding these strings !
 Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried using [Regular Expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex)?

Comment: Do you know the exact names of the files you are looking for, but not their locations?  Or do you want all text files in `Sigma`?  More information on exactly what you need will help.

Comment: @Trenin I just know The parent location for example in this case C:\Users\RDep  .

Comment: @omid It sounds like you know where you are looking, but not what you are looking for.  If I have a file X in your c:\users\rdep directory, how do you know if it one you want or not?  Are you looking for all the files in this directory?  What criteria are you using for determining which files you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 'Regular Expression' is good method, however, in your file, matching pattern is quite simple. So, I just use `find` function of `std::string`.
This code is just a little code snippet. So, there are several improvements points, also.
For example, through using `vector<string>` for finding pattern, it will be easier to add finding patterns and handle the patterns.

```
//Originally, each data is from your file.
//but, this is just sample.
std::istringstream input;
input.str("Directory of C:\\Users\\RDep\n"
            "01/07/2014  09:32 PM               569 GNU CLISP 2.49.lnk\n"
            "01/07/2014  09:38 PM               493 lsp 23.fas\n"
            "01/07/2014  09:38 PM                28 lsp 23.lib\n"
            "01/07/2014  09:35 PM                35 lsp 23.lsp\n");

//to find pattern
std::string directory_pattern   = "Directory of ";
std::string lsp_pattern         = "lsp ";

std::size_t found = std::string::npos;

for (std::string line; std::getline(input, line); ) {
    found = line.find(directory_pattern);    
    if (found!=std::string::npos)
    {
        //write on file for 'directory'
        std::string directory_name(line, found + directory_pattern.length() );
        std::cout << "\nDirectory : " << directory_name;

        continue;
    }

    found = line.find(lsp_pattern);    
    if (found!=std::string::npos)
    {           
        //write on file for 'lsp'
        std::string lsp_name(line, found );
        std::cout << "\nlsp : " << lsp_name;

        continue;
    }
}
```

Above code will print like below,

```
Directory : C:\\Users\\RDep
lsp : lsp 23.fas
lsp : lsp 23.lib
lsp : lsp 23.lsp
```

Comment: Nopes It is not easy . I have other files too .those names "lsp Sigma... " depends on input file.So I Can't use It here unless I write all possible names ! that takes a full year I think :)

Answer (score -2):

Try something like:

```
bool foo(char* filename)
{

    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(f == NULL)
        return false;

    char buffer[1024];
    char pattern[] = "C:\\Users\\RDep";

    while(fgets(buffer, 1024, f) != NULL)
    {
        if(strstr(buffer, pattern) != null)
        {
            // Found pattern!
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hardly a C++ response!

Comment: Ty but It was the easy part ! I still have no idea how to find  lsp 23.lsp , Zop.txt ,...  !

Comment: You find all of the strings the same way - you just change the pattern to "lsp 23.lsp" and use `strstr` to find the pattern. Repeat it for every pattern you are looking for.

Comment: @UriY The problem is I dont know any names in it I just know the location here C:\Users\RDep (It depends on user choice). All other stuffs depends on the input file .

Comment: @omid What input file are you talking about?  The original question doesn't mention an input file.  Perhaps you should clarify the question a bit.